# 18.10 new install freezes with intel_pipe_update_end [i915] / Atomic update failure

Tags: nvidia, freeze, 18.10, acpi, nvidia-geforce

My 18.10 installation started to freeze a few days ago and strangely, even reverting to trusty 18.04 did not help. I am submitting this from Windoze and feel defeated.

- After reinstall of 18.10 the system freezes within 10 seconds to a minute, from dmesg:

  `kernel: [   54.156332] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=3401 end=3402) time 379 us, min 1192, max 1199, scanline start 1191, end 1217`

  Before the freeze I can use a terminal, but `sudo ls` takes several seconds, and as soon as I open Firefox the FF icon gets bigger and bang the system freezes, same for typing into the super-key window after a few letters.
- same with Xorg and nvidia driver
- following https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/intel-microcode-atomic-update.html
  I added  /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf containing

  `options i915 enable_psr=0`

  This really seemed to help for a few minutes... but then the system froze again.
- I reverted back to 18.04, which had worked for many months, but could not install a working system this time. After the boot message it went into `Emergency mode` with

  `tpm_crb MSFT0101:00 [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer.`
- Adding `acpi_os=!` to the boot loader does not help.
- I have the latest BIOS installed with fastboot off.
- Live USB 18.04 and 18.10 boot fine.
- In desperation I disabled secure boot half way through my trouble, as I received `PKCS#7 signature` errors; not sure how relevant this could be. Troubleshooting above is with secure boot off and updates installed.

Please help as I am submitting this from Windoze ...)

Answer (score 0):

Could be [an installer bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-installer/+bug/1810774)

How to work around:

- During install disable network and disable any update of drivers and software.
- Upon restart the graphics will freeze again, but recovery options do work this time.
- Plug in LAN cable, start in recovery mode, enable networking, then drop into root.

  ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
  ```

See [Ubuntu Linux Install Nvidia Driver (Latest Proprietary Driver)](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/).

Now graphics will work. I then switched to using the NVIDIA driver using "Software & Updates":

[image: screenshot]

My issue and a solution is also described [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/).

Comment: So now running `journalctl -b0 -p3 | grep intel_pipe_update_end` in your case doesn't return `kernel: [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A`? People think is related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1660619) (maybe a workaround on [comment #14](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1660619/comments/14)).

Comment: `journalctl -b0 -p3 | grep intel_pipe_update_end` comes up empty after following my workaround from Jan 7th.

Comment: Could you please paste the output of `grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub`? I still have this error 10 times even with Nvidia driver (`dpkg -l | grep $(ubuntu-drivers list)`).

Comment: Outputs are:   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and `ii  nvidia-driver-390   390.87-0ubuntu1     amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage`